# Getting started with PHP/Laravel - Adding Http:// and Https:// on to URL Path

Tags: php, validation, url, laravel, input

I am attempting to have a input field for adding a website/url. All I want to require to successfully submit the form is www.domainname.com; however, after submission I want to add back on http:// or https:// if it was not added by the person submitting the form.

The validation is along the lines of the following,

```
public function name($id) {

$input = Input::all();
$validator = Validator::make(
  $input,
  array(
    'website' => 'active_url',
  )
);

}
```

For this to work an if statement is needed. I have tried inserting something along the lines of the code listed below, but have not had any luck.

```
if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
  $url = "http://" . $url;
}
```

I am fairly new to PHP and just starting to use Laravel, so I apologize in advance if there is any confusion or lack of information. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
if (stripos($url, "http://") === false && stripos($url, "https://") === false) {
  $url = "http://" . $url;
}
```

`stripos` is case-insensitive, so it shouldn't matter if the user typed in lowercase letters or not in the url prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply just strip the scheme to begin with and then add it.

```
$url = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $url);
$url = "http://" . $url;
```

Or

```
$url = ltrim('http://', $url);
$url = ltrim('https://', $url);
$url = 'http://' . $url;
```

Or

```
if (!preg_match('#^http(s)?://#', $url)) {
  $url = 'http://' . $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think no need for validation,.. maybe it could help you

@alix axel code

```
function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
```